# On the proof of limsup is the largest cluster point

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm studing the following proof:

[image]

the proof for the case $x^* \in \mathbb{R}$ is as follows. Define $y_n = \sup_{n \geq k} x_n$ so $x^* = \inf_{n} y_n$:

[image]

My problem is at the last paragraph: "the interval $(x^* - \epsilon, x^* + \epsilon)$ must contain infinitely many terms of the sequence $(x_n)$". I know that for each $n$ we can find $x_k$ such that $x_k > x^* - \epsilon$, but **why** is it true that $x_k < x^* + \epsilon$ ?

Comment: Because $x^{*}$ is the infimum $\inf_{n} y_n$, so for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $n$ such that $y_n < x^{*} + \varepsilon$, as $y_n$ is itself the supremum of $x_k$ we have that for any $k \geq n$; $x_k \leq y_n < x^{*} + \varepsilon$.

Comment: That is perfect :)

Comment: I’ll post it as an answer if you don’t mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in my previous comment, you can justify $x_k < x^{*} + \varepsilon$ by noting that $x^{*}$ is by definition the infimum $\inf_n y_n$, so for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $n$, such that $y_n < x^{*} + \varepsilon$. $y_n$ is itself a supremum over $x_k$, so we have for any $k \geq n$ the desired inequality: $x_k \leq y_n < x^{*} + \varepsilon$.

Comment: sorry for my stupidity but one little question: I can understand "for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $n$, such that $y_n<x^∗+\epsilon$", but to really establish that $x_k \in (x^* - \epsilon, x^* + \epsilon)$, such $n$ **must be the same**  number assumed as in the "for each $n$, some $k \geq n$" part, and I still can't see why it is true :(

Comment: to clarify, we already have that for all $\epsilon > 0$, for all $n$ there exists $k \geq n$ such that $x_k > x^* - \epsilon$; what we have here is that for *some* $n'$ such that $y_{n'}<x^∗+\epsilon$, and it is not shown that $n = n'$.

Comment: The trick is to turn the statements around: first pick $\varepsilon > 0$ then we have (some) $n'$ such that $y_{n'}<x^{*}+\epsilon$ and therefore $x_{k} < x^{*}+\epsilon$ for each $k \geq n'$. Now that we know the $n'$ doing the trick, we apply the other statement which close the issue. That's because for all $n$ (in particular for $n'$), with our $\varepsilon$ fixed, we can find a $k \geq n'$ such that $x_k > x^* - \varepsilon$, as $k \geq n'$ and we kept the value of $\varepsilon$, we can safely say  $x_{k} < x^{*}+\epsilon$, therefore $x_{k} \in (x^{*} - \varepsilon, x^{*} + \varepsilon)$

Comment: That solves it, thanks!